# GitBook: Why do appear `1.` prefixes and how can I delete them?

Tags: gitbook

This is my `SUMMARY.md` file:

```
# ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ

1. [Введение](README.md)
  1. [Назначение](chapters/001-introduction/README.md)
  1. [Соглашения, принятые в документах](chapters/001-introduction/agreements.md)
  1. [Границы проекта](chapters/001-introduction/project-borders.md)
  1. [Ссылки](chapters/001-introduction/references.md)
1. [Общее описание](chapters/002-common-description/README.md)
  1. [Общий взгляд на продукт](chapters/002-common-description/overview.md)
  1. [Классы и характеристики пользователей](chapters/002-common-description/users.md)
  1. [Операционная среда](chapters/002-common-description/system-requirements.md)
  1. [Ограничения дизайна и реализации](chapters/002-common-description/restrictions.md)
  1. [Предположения и зависимости](chapters/002-common-description/assumptions-and-dependencies.md)
```

This is the PDF publishing result:

[image]

Why do appear `1.` prefixes and how can I delete them?

Comment: I don't know anything about gitbook but I'd guess that it interprets `# ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ` as a chapter title (for chapter 1) and therefore sets the numbering accordingly. Have you checked whether gitbook allows you to set the numbering style for the table of contents / sections ?

Comment: If I delete `# ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ` then the problem doesn't disappear.